# Adding href in php from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, href

```
<ul> 
<li> Telephone number : <?php  echo $row[3]?> </li> 
<li> Website : <a href = "<?php  echo $row[4]?>" ></a> </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Output screen]

$row[4] represents the column in database that has the link to website.
I'm trying this code to get href but it's not working for some reason. Any hints what am I doing wrong here?

If I echo it without making it an href then it's working fine. So my database connection is perfectly working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like missing ;

Comment: Try `<a href="<?php  echo $row[4];?>" ></a>` - so remove spaces and add `;` at the end of `echo`

Comment: Nopes still not working

Comment: Can you show what it generates.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the PHP you've provided, so there's more to this than what you've shared so far.

Comment: "Looks like missing ;" one line PHP code within `<?php ?>` does not require `;` @Valdars see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0dc17ba6e9cae4f9ce8fb41b558a21686bca6a01

Comment: But without the href part it's working correctly fine. So it's some error with href tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you filled only the href attribute of the link. The text to be displayed must be put between the link tags:

```
<a href="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>"><?php echo $row[4]; ?></a>
```

Comment: Oh now I realize my mistake. Thanks alot :D

Comment: little hint @RamshaKhalid valid your html here  https://validator.w3.org/   (three different methods of validation).. if it's does not validate you use wrong html formatting or wrong tags within tags..Besides unvalidated html can display wrong within browsers.